# Return null even the value does exist in database WinForm Entity Framework 5

Tags: winforms, entity-framework

Something odd is happening. I have a form with 2 labels and 2 textboxes 1 button. In the button action method I get the values from the textboxes and pass them to a Linq query, like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Username = textBoxUsername.ToString();
        string Password = textBoxPassword.ToString();
        User admin = new User();
        admin = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == Username && u.Pass==Password);
        if (admin != null)
            MessageBox.Show("Succesfully");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Fail");
    }
```

admin keeps return null even the value does exist in database.
But If I change to this 
`admin = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == "Admin" Pass=="12345");` it RETURNS the object as it's supposed to do. 
Can you tell me what is wrong here in my code and what is the solution. Thank you very much
(I'm sorry if you find this stupid :(  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
string Username = textBoxUsername.ToString();
```

returns the value `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:`, not the text typed as the username

you need to use the property Text

```
string Username = textBoxUsername.Text;
```

the same for the password field.

Generically, if you use the `ToString()` from an instance of a class, the return is the fully qualified name of the class unless the class overrides the ToString method returning something customized using the class instance data. (An example are the numerous overrides of the `ToString(some_type_of_mask)` used for numeric and date formatting)